# hyperlink with a text obtained from database

Tags: c#

I'm reading from a database into a table. I want the selected text variable to be generated with a hyperlink to redirect me to another asp page. how could that happen?? below is my code:

```
foreach(var album in data)
{
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();

    tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell()
    { 
        Text = album.AlbumName,
    });

    tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    tblData.Rows.Add(tr);

    var album_songs = bl.GetSongsByAlbum(album.Id_Album);

    Table childTbl = new Table();
    childTbl.CssClass = "pure-table-horizontal";

    foreach(var song in album_songs)
    {
        TableRow tr2 = new TableRow();
        tr2.Cells.Add(new TableCell()
        {
            Text = song.SongName
        });
        childTbl.Rows.Add(tr2); 
    }

    tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    cell.Width = 100;

    tr.Cells.Add(cell);
    cell = new TableCell();
    cell.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Padding, "0");
    cell.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Margin, "0");
    cell.Controls.Add(childTbl);
    tr.Cells.Add(cell);
    tblData.Rows.Add(tr); 
}
}
```

please rewrite the code with the hyperlink

Comment: where is your hyperlink generation code

Comment: I want the text to be along with a hyperlink to an aspx page

Comment: your comment is not clear. Do you want to generate the hyperlink dynamically and assign the text that will come from DB?

Comment: I want when the text is read from the database to assign a hyperlink along with it so that the user canclick the text field to another aspx page

Comment: look in to the answer i have posted and let me know if you need any clarifictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
 Table t = new Table();
 foreach(var album in data)
 {
   TableRow tr = new TableRow();
   tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = album.AlbumName });        
   HyperLink link = new HyperLink![enter image description here][2]();
   link.ID = "HyperLink1";
   link.NavigateUrl = "~/files/aspx_pages/.aspx";//Give the name of the aspx page that you want to navigate
   link.Text = "Album1 Link";
   TableCell tc = new TableCell();
   tc.Controls.Add(link);
   tr.Cells.Add(tc);
   t.Rows.Add(tr);
 }
 Page.Controls.Add(t);
```

Generate the `HyperLink` as follow

```
HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
link.ID = "HyperLink1";
link.NavigateUrl = "~/files/aspx_pages/" + ValueFromYourDB + ".aspx"
link.Text= "Text from DB";
```

After this add `link` to the table that you are preparing

Comment: didn't understand what exactly to do take into consideration im a beginner. this is my requirement:I have a table albums with albumName and AlbumArtist I want a table showing each albumName along with its Album artist and the albumName should be hyperlinked to redirect me to the list of songs of that album

Comment: Ok i understood your requirement.

Comment: so?is that possible??

Comment: See the edited code to generate the table and the content you want