# get the ID of a selected value in the drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an Album table with an Id_album attribute. and a songs table with Id_song attribute and Id_album as foreign key attribute. In the aspx page I have a drop down list of the album names to be selected to get its Id and use that Id in the songs table to add new songs ofthat album *depending on Id)
what I have done so far returns for me Id_album 1 whenever an album name is selected from the drop down list. In other words, the songs are all added to album of Id=1.what is going wrong??

this is the aspx page:

```
public partial class newSongs : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MusicStoreBL bl = new MusicStoreBL();
        var data = bl.GetAlbums();
         //GetAlbums is a function that returns the Id_album, AlbumName
        albums.DataSource = data;
        //albums is the HTML dropdownlist
        albums.DataTextField = "AlbumName";
        albums.DataValueField = "Id_Album";
        albums.DataBind();
    }

    protected void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Song song = new Song();
        //Song is a get/set model

        song.Id_album = int.Parse(albums.SelectedValue);

        song.SongName = songName.Text;
        song.SongAuthor = author.Text;
        song.MusicArtist = songArtist.Text;
        song.Genre = genre.Text;

        MusicStoreBL bl = new MusicStoreBL();
        bl.CreateNewSong(song);
        Response.Redirect("albumSelection.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your data binding code in the Page Load event handler inside the following if statement:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    MusicStoreBL bl = new MusicStoreBL();
    var data = bl.GetAlbums();
    //GetAlbums is a function that returns the Id_album, AlbumName
    albums.DataSource = data;
    //albums is the HTML dropdownlist
    albums.DataTextField = "AlbumName";
    albums.DataValueField = "Id_Album";
    albums.DataBind();
}
```

This way you fetch your data only once and then you bind them to the corresponding drop down list control. Otherwise, each time you trigger a postback, like selecting an element from your drop down list control or clicking on a button and so on, your data bind code in the `Page_Load` runs from the start.

So why you get all the time the Id=1?

The reason why you get every time as an Id the 1 is the fact that every time you click the save the code in the `Page_Load` runs. The data bind happens and the first item of the drop down list is the selected one.

Comment: You welocme dude. I am glad that I helped.

Comment: @mohammad : accept as answer as this solved your problem...which will help others... :)

Comment: @Christos hope you can help me with my next issue :)

Comment: @mohammad sure thing. What's up.

Comment: @Christos please check this question see if you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480545/hyperlink-with-a-text-obtained-from-database/26481030#26481030